# How to find big-O for a nested loop which has both down and up counts

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

How to I find time complexity for the following code?

sum `j` from `j=n` to `n/(3^(j-1))`

this is the pseudocode from which I got the summation.

```
j=n
while (j>=1)
  for (i=1 to n)
    x=x+1
  j=j/3
}
```

Comment: Unless j is less than zero, the sum is j and your sum computation is wrong.  n/(3^(j-1)) <= n. if j is non-negative.  So... summing from j=n to something less than n is... what... just n?  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suppose `n = 3^k`, the number of iterations for the outer loop will be `k = log_3(n)`. As we have a loop with `n` iteration (the inner loop), the total time complexity will be `T(n) = \Theta(n \log_3(n))`.

Moreover, as `log_3(n)/log_2(n) = log_3(2) = constant`, we can have `T(n) = \Theta(n log(n))` (`log(n) == log_2(n)`).

Answer (score 1):

This would be O(n log_3(n)). Indeed, at each iteration you're left with a third of the previous length to cover. So n + n/3 + n/9 + n/27 + ...

Comment: Or you could just say **O(n log n)**, since log_3(n) = log(n)/log(3) = k·log(n) (where k is a constant)

Comment: Yup that works too. More in line with Big O notation.